# Direct product of cyclic group with itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $R$ be the direct product of $C_p$ with itself. Show that $R$ is an abelian group of order $p^2$ and $R$ is not cylic.

Comment: Is this a homework question? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Have you shown any of those properties?

Comment: The first question should be clear. As to the second, is there an element of order $p^2$ in $R$?

Comment: This is first step of theorem's proof which says that if $p$ is a prime integre, then there exists a noncommutative ring of order $p^2$.

Comment: That does not actually address any of the questions.

Comment: No, I haven't shown yet.

Comment: It should really be clear that the group is abelian of order $p^2$ simply from the definition of the direct product. Where are you stuck trying to show those two parts?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I see now. It should not be difficult to show the first property. However, I have problem with the fact that $R$ is not cylic. Could you help me with this, please?

Comment: Cyclic means that there is an element whose order is the order of the group, i.e $p^2$. What are the elements of $C_p \times C_p$? Is there an element of order $p^2$?

Comment: I don't think that this question should be closed - the OP is interacting with the comments, so this is not just a "Tell me the answer plz!" question.

Answer (score 2):

Just so this question isn't left hanging without an answer:

Suppose $G=C_p\times C_p$. Then $G$ has order $p^2$, as $(a^{i_1}, b^{j_1})=(a^{i_2}, b^{j_2})$ if and only if $i_1=i_2\text{ mod }p$ and $j_1=j_2\text{ mod }p$.

To prove that $G$ abelian, you should try and prove the stronger property: that the direct product of any two abelian groups is abelian. To do this, suppose $H$ and $K$ are abelian, then show that $(h_1, k_1)(h_2, k_2)=(h_2, k_2)(h_1, k_2)$ for $h_1, h_2\in H$ and $k_1, k_2\in K$ arbitrary.

To prove that $G$ is non-cyclic, prove that it has exponent $p$. That is, prove that $(a^i, b^j)^p=(1, 1)$ for all $0\leq i, j<p$.